# how to synchronize near realtime reads from a sql server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

We have a reporting app thats needs to update it's charts as the data gets written to it's corresponding table. (the report is based off just one table). Currently we just keep the last read sessionid + rowid (unique combo) in memory and a polling timer just does a select where rowid > what we have in memory (to get the latest rows added). Timer runs every second or so and the fast sql reader does it's job well. So far so good. However I feel this is not optimal because sometimes there are pauses in the data writes due to the process by design. (user clicking the pause button on the system that writes data ..). Meanwhile our timer keeps hitting the db and does not get any new rows. No errors or anything. How is this situation normally handled. The app that writes the data is separate from the reporting app. The 2 apps run on different machines. **Bottomline : How to get data into a c# app as and when it is written into a sql server table without polling unnecessarily.** thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has the capability to notify a waiting application for changes, see [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/). This is how [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) works. But this will only work up to a certain threshold of data change rate. If your data changes too frequently then the cost of setting up a query notification just to be immediately invalidated by receiving the notification is too much. For really high end rates of changes the best place is to notify the application directly from the writer, usually achieved via some forms of a pub-sub infrastructure.

You could also attempt a mixed approach: pool for changes in your display application and only set up a query notification *if* there are no changes. This way you avoid the cost of constantly setting up Query Notifications when the rate of changes is high, but you also get the benefits of non-pooling once the writes settle down.

Comment: Your suggestions should work. I will play with this in detail using it maybe in combination with with sql clr assembly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only 'proper' way is to poll, however you can reduce the cost of this polling by having SQL wait in a loop (make sure you WAITFOR something like 30ms each loop pass) until data is available (or a set time period elapses, e.g. 10s). This is commonly used when writing SQL pseudoqueues.

You could use extended procs - but that is fragile, or, you could drop messages into MSMQ.

Comment: Using `WAITFOR(RECEIVE)` does no poll if you're willing to use actual queues, not 'pseudoqueues'. This is exactly what `SqlDependency` does.

Comment: No @Remus, the WAITFOR that halts for a time period (aka sleep). Fyi, SSB is doing exactly this in the background; whick you quickly learn if you write your own SSB client library.

Comment: Oh, as to the reason for the WAITFOR/sleep is the loop would peg the CPU otherwise.

Comment: I can tell you for sure `WAITFOR(RECEIVE)` is not polling. Pending `WAITFOR(RECEIVE)` threads are notified whenever there are new messages available.

Comment: @Remus Your C# client still polls in the same fashion as my answer - as demonstrated by the open source msft SSB client. That is the point I am making. There may be tricks on the SQL end, yes. What is you point?

Comment: The C# client will post a `WAITFOR(RECEIVE)`. The statement will *block* on the server until messages are available (or it times out). This is quite different from 'polling' because there is no active query being run (there is no check for messages, wait, check for messages, wait in a loop). You may call this 'poll' from the C# library POV (it issues a command), but I would disagree the term is correct in the context. Polling implies *active sampling of status*, which does not occur with SSB.

Comment: @Remus ah right. Still this was *the* way to do queues in SQL before SSB - and is still viable when SSB doesn't fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

If your reporting application is running on a single server then you can have the application that is writing the data to SQL Server also send a message to the reporting app letting it know that new data is available.

However, having your application connect to the server to see if new records have been added is the most common way of doing it.  As long as you do the polling on a background thread, it shouldn't effect the performance of your application at all.

Answer (score -1):

you will need to push the event out of the database into the realm of your application.

The application will need to listen for the message. (you will need to decide what listening means - what port, what protocol, what format etc.)

The database will send the message based on the event through a trigger. (you need to look up how to use external application logic in triggers)

Comment: -1 because triggers connecting to an application for notifying updates is a recipe for disaster

Comment: well.. i basically agree.. but the OP asked for an alternative to polling...  also, i did not advocate a direct connection to the app for communication - the broadcast should ideally be independent - not caring if there is an active listener.

Comment: OK, perhaps I misread it, but as I read it is basically 'connect to the app for communication from a trigger'. Care to elaborate a bit what do you mean by 'use external application logic in triggers'?

Comment: in general, instead of trigger code like PL/SQL - you might use something like java, or be able to call an external procedure or program.  since TSQL or PLSQL generally do not interface with things outside the database, ou will need to use one of these type languages instead (if supported)

Comment: @Randy, Your solution sounds bit too heavy with db triggers etc. I am looking at some of the other solutions posted here. thx